# I am getting a timeout exception

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open the whatsapp.web which I am able to do so

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\admin\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Session Storage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
```

I am also able to punch in the mobile number in whatsapp.web

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Find the WhatsApp chat search box and enter the customer's phone number
    search_box = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@contenteditable='true']")
    search_box.send_keys(f"+{row['Contact Number']}")
    time.sleep(2)
    search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)
```

However, I am stuck with the below code.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)  

message_box = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@contenteditable='true']")
print(message_box)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='_21ryq']//iframe"))
message_box.send_keys(f"Hi, just a friendly reminder that your next purchase is coming up soon!")
time.sleep(2)
message_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
```

I am getting the error as

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='_2A8P4']//iframe"}
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.63)
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Python is whitespace-sensitive and your code is so messed up we can't tell what it is supposed to do.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message, not just the final line.

Comment: What does this have to do with Pandas? I only see Selenium code.

Comment: Please provide a [MRE] for debugging, including the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the error occurs at:

```py
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='_21ryq']//iframe")
```

In the provided error message, the XPATH is `//div[@class='_2A8P4']//iframe` though, which is different. Maybe you forgot to sync with the code?

Looks like the class is always `'_'+"some_random_string"` and not consistent. In that case, you'll need another locator